# Python tarfile module creates folder in itself, instead of just a file

Tags: python, windows, gzip, 7zip

When I run the following script, it creates a gzip file called `hello.gz`. Inside the gzip is a folder called `hello`, and inside of the folder is my text file `goodbye.txt`.

Can it be set to have the gzip file contain the text file directly, instead of having the text file be in a folder called `hello`?

```
import tarfile
with tarfile.open("hello.gz", "w:gz") as tar:
    tar.add("goodbye.txt")
```

I'm running Windows Server 2008 and Python 2.7.

Note: if I run this command, the gzip does contain only the text file, and not the folder:

```
7z.exe a -tgzip hello.gz goodbye.txt
```

But I'm curious if it can be done with the `tarfile` module.

Comment: i don't think it does. if you extract it with `tar -xzf hello.gz`, you end up with `goodbye.txt` in the current directory.

Comment: @twasbrillig How are you unpacking/decompressing hello.gz? Some utilities (like `atool`) will create a directory for you based on the name of the file you're unpacking.

Comment: @Turn I'm not unpacking it yet. The goal right now is just to create it.

Comment: If you're not unpacking it the how do you know it is creating the folder `hello`?

Comment: I was using the 7-zip File Manager to open it and see if it worked.